# Visual Studio 2017 Lock Up: can't start, uninstall, or reinstall

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, visual-studio-2017, uninstallation

I seem to have gotten my visual studio 2017 installation into an impossible state.

It started when I wanted to create a setup project to make installation of my solution easier. I found [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) add on for visual studio 2017 and downloaded and then ran the vsix file. The installation seemed to run fine, though I had to tell it to close visual studio since I still had it running in the background, until it reached the end at which point it hung for a long time. About an hour later I decided to just cancel the installation. When I then tried to go into visual studio, I was presented with the following dialog

[image: "The setup for this installation of Visual Studio is not complete. Please run the Visual Studio Installer again to correct the issue."]

I then decided to try and re-run the vsix file, but this time just be patient and wait for it to finish. However, this time I was told that couldn't run because it was already installed.

[image: "This extension is already installed to all applicable products."]

So. I think, I'll uninstall Visual Studio 2017 and reinstall from scratch.

Nope. The uninstaller hangs on 0% and when I go to close the window...

[image: "It looks like you're installing or modifying another product right now. Please wait until all other operations are finished and try again."]

And finally. I thought. What if I just run the installer again, and install Visual Studio 2017 over the top of itself. That should be fine, and should reset the state of the application to normal. No. I run the installer, and nothing. I see an extraction window with progress bar, but then that disappears. I can see the bootstrapper process in Task Manager, but there is no window. Nothing happens.

[image: Processes in Task Manager]

So. My question is, is there a way for me to either reset the state of Visual Studio so that it can be used again, or, alternatively, is there a way for me to purge my machine of this application without use of the uninstaller?